# Trigger to update a table based on data in other table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Need to create a trigger, when Items.Status is updated to 20 from any of the value which are less than 20, not values greater than 20.

The trigger should update the Status table for the corresponding Item_Id with Status.Status_Desc = "Packed"

So far I have been able to create a trigger like below which compiles fine but isn't giving me the intended result . Please help

```
create or replace trigger test_trg 
after update on items
referencing old as old new as new
for each row 


--select item_id into
begin
  if (:old.status < 20 and :new.status=20) then
      update status 
      set status_desc='packed'
      where Item_Id =1  /*Justfor testing purpose, this need to be matched with item_id in ITEMS table */
  end if;

end;
```

The script for creating the tables

```
  CREATE TABLE "ITEMS" ("ITEM_ID" NUMBER, "ITEM_NAME" VARCHAR2(100), "STATUS" NUMBER)
REM INSERTING into ITEMS
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into ITEMS (ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,STATUS) values (1,'Test',10);
Insert into ITEMS (ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,STATUS) values (2,'Test1',30);



  CREATE TABLE "STATUS" ("ITEM_ID" NUMBER, "STATUS_DESC" VARCHAR2(100))
REM INSERTING into STATUS
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into STATUS (ITEM_ID,STATUS_DESC) values (1,'testing');
Insert into STATUS (ITEM_ID,STATUS_DESC) values (2,'testing');
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2b38/2.  Are you checking the contents of your `STATUS` table from another session without having committed in the session you ran an `UPDATE` from?

Comment: @LukeWoodward No luke.. 

update status 
      set status='packed'
      where Item_Id =1  

in this I need to set item_id should be the same item_id as the ITEMS table. I have hardcoded 1 for testing only

Comment: @LukeWoodward I have updated the trigger . it was the field status_desc field which needed to be updated and not status field

Comment: In that case, use `:new.item_id` instead of just `1`.

Comment: This is not :new.itemid, it has to be  :old.itemid;